# Why are my Uniforms and Storage Buffers showing the wrong data in Vulkan using GLSL?

Tags: c++, vulkan, raytracing, compute-shader

EDIT2: I found the error, the code that creates the buffer was overwriting one of the storage buffers with one of the uniform buffers that I create afterwards because of a copy paste error.

So I'm currently trying to adapt the Ray Tracing Weekend project (https://raytracing.github.io/) from a CPU program into a compute shader using Vulkan. I'm writing the compute shader using GLSL which is compiled to SPIRV.

I send the scene in the form of a struct containing arrays of structs to the GPU as a storage buffer which looks like this on the CPU (world_gpu being the storage buffer):

```
struct sphere_gpu
{
    point3 centre;
    float radius;
};

struct material_gpu
{
    vec3 albedo;
    float refraction_index;
    float fuzz;
    uint32_t material_type;
};

struct world_gpu
{
    sphere_gpu spheres[484];
    material_gpu materials[484];
    uint32_t size;
};
```

and this on the GPU:

```
// Struct definitions to mirror the CPU representation
struct sphere{
    vec4 centre;
    float radius;
};

struct material{
    vec4 albedo;
    float refraction_index;
    float fuzz;
    uint material_type;
};

// Input scene
layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer world{
    sphere[MAX_SPHERES] spheres;
    material[MAX_SPHERES] materials;
    uint size;
} wrld;
```

I've already fixed the alignment problem for vec3 on the CPU side by using alignas(16) for my vec3 type: `class alignas (16) vec3`, and changing the type on the GPU representation to be vec4s as shown above to match the alignment of the data I'm sending over

However, whilst testing this I only seem to be able to read 0s for the spheres when I inspect the data after the compute shader has finished running (I've hijacked my output pixel array in the shader which I write debug data to so that I can read it and debug certain things).

Is there anything obviously stupid that I'm doing here, aside from being a Vulkan noob in general?

EDIT:
Here's my buffer uploading code. set_manual_buffer_data is where the data is actually copied to the buffer, create_manual_buffer is where the buffer and memory itself are created.

```
    template <typename T>
    void set_manual_buffer_data(vk::Device device, vk::Buffer& buffer, vk::DeviceMemory& buffer_memory, T* elements, uint32_t num_elements,uint32_t element_size)
    {
        uint32_t size = element_size * num_elements;
        // Get a pointer to the device memory
        void* buffer_ptr = device.mapMemory(buffer_memory, 0, element_size * num_elements);
        // Copy data to buffer
        memcpy(buffer_ptr, elements, element_size * num_elements);

        device.unmapMemory(buffer_memory);
    }

    // call with physical_device.getMemoryProperties() for second argument
    void create_manual_buffer(vk::Device device, vk::PhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties memory_properties, uint32_t queue_family_index, const uint32_t buffer_size, vk::BufferUsageFlagBits buffer_usage, vk::Buffer& buffer, vk::DeviceMemory& buffer_memory)
    {
        vk::BufferCreateInfo buffer_create_info{};
        buffer_create_info.flags = vk::BufferCreateFlags();
        buffer_create_info.size = buffer_size;
        buffer_create_info.usage = buffer_usage; // Play with this
        buffer_create_info.sharingMode = vk::SharingMode::eExclusive; //concurrent or exclusive
        buffer_create_info.pQueueFamilyIndices = &queue_family_index;
        buffer_create_info.queueFamilyIndexCount = 1;


        buffer = device.createBuffer(buffer_create_info);

        vk::MemoryRequirements memory_requirements = device.getBufferMemoryRequirements(buffer);

        uint32_t memory_type_index = static_cast<uint32_t>(~0);
        vk::DeviceSize memory_heap_size = static_cast<uint32_t>(~0);

        for (uint32_t current_memory_type_index = 0; current_memory_type_index < memory_properties.memoryTypeCount; ++current_memory_type_index)
        {
            // search for desired memory type from the device memory 
            vk::MemoryType MemoryType = memory_properties.memoryTypes[current_memory_type_index];
            if ((vk::MemoryPropertyFlagBits::eHostVisible & MemoryType.propertyFlags) &&
                (vk::MemoryPropertyFlagBits::eHostCoherent & MemoryType.propertyFlags))
            {
                memory_heap_size = memory_properties.memoryHeaps[MemoryType.heapIndex].size;
                memory_type_index = current_memory_type_index;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Create device memory
        vk::MemoryAllocateInfo buffer_allocate_info(memory_requirements.size, memory_type_index);
        buffer_memory = device.allocateMemory(buffer_allocate_info);

        device.bindBufferMemory(buffer, buffer_memory, 0);
    }
```

This code is then called here (I haven't got to the refactoring stage yet so please forgive the spaghetti):

```
    std::vector<vk::Buffer> uniform_buffers;
    std::vector<vk::DeviceMemory> uniform_buffers_memory;
    std::vector<vk::Buffer> storage_buffers;
    std::vector<vk::DeviceMemory> storage_buffers_memory;
    
    
    void run_compute(Vulkan_Wrapper &vulkan, Vulkan_Compute &compute, world_gpu *world, color* image, uint32_t image_size, image_info img_info, camera_gpu camera_gpu)
    {
        vulkan.init();
    
        uniform_buffers.resize(2);
        uniform_buffers_memory.resize(2);
        storage_buffers.resize(2);
        storage_buffers_memory.resize(2);
        
        vulkan.create_manual_buffer(vulkan.m_device, vulkan.m_physical_device.getMemoryProperties(),
            vulkan.m_queue_family_index, sizeof(world_gpu),
            vk::BufferUsageFlagBits::eStorageBuffer, storage_buffers[0],
            storage_buffers_memory[0]);
        vulkan.create_manual_buffer(vulkan.m_device, vulkan.m_physical_device.getMemoryProperties(),
            vulkan.m_queue_family_index, image_size * sizeof(color),
            vk::BufferUsageFlagBits::eStorageBuffer, storage_buffers[1],
            storage_buffers_memory[1]);
    
        vulkan.set_manual_buffer_data(vulkan.m_device, storage_buffers[0], storage_buffers_memory[0], world, 1, sizeof(world_gpu));
        vulkan.set_manual_buffer_data(vulkan.m_device, storage_buffers[1], storage_buffers_memory[1], image, image_size, sizeof(color));
    
        vulkan.create_manual_buffer(vulkan.m_device, vulkan.m_physical_device.getMemoryProperties(),
            vulkan.m_queue_family_index, sizeof(image_info),
            vk::BufferUsageFlagBits::eUniformBuffer, storage_buffers[0],
            uniform_buffers_memory[0]);
        vulkan.create_manual_buffer(vulkan.m_device, vulkan.m_physical_device.getMemoryProperties(),
            vulkan.m_queue_family_index, sizeof(camera_gpu),
            vk::BufferUsageFlagBits::eUniformBuffer, uniform_buffers[1],
            uniform_buffers_memory[1]);
    
        vulkan.set_manual_buffer_data(vulkan.m_device, uniform_buffers[0], uniform_buffers_memory[0], &img_info, 1, sizeof(img_info));
        vulkan.set_manual_buffer_data(vulkan.m_device, uniform_buffers[1], uniform_buffers_memory[1], &camera_gpu, 1, sizeof(camera_gpu));
// Run pipeline etc
```

I should note that it works perfectly fine when I check the values stored in the image storage buffer (storage_buffers_memory[1]), it's the other 3 that is giving me difficulties

Comment: Looks alright to me. If you're getting zeros for everything then I suspect your problem rather lies in the upload code instead of the buffer specification. Could you share that part?

Comment: @IGarFieldI I've made an edit showing the buffer uploading code, I can't seem to find the problem here that makes it any different from the image storage buffer which works fine

Comment: @ZTaylor97: "*Struct definitions to mirror the CPU representation*" Wrong.

Comment: @NicolBolas Your comment was extremely helpful, thankyou